# Location: GPS/network permissions: wanted if available

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want my application to access GPS/Network locations if they are availabe. 
I don't want Google Play to filter out devices without GPS/Network locator.

How should I do this?

Currently I have this on my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
```

However, I am not sure it that is enough, because http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions-features states that:

-permission *ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION* implies `android.hardware.location.network` and 
`android.hardware.location` features requirement

-permission *ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION implies `android.hardware.location.gps` and 
`android.hardware.location`

Do I also have to add 
`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />`
and
`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />` ?

Why?

Shouldn't `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />` be enough?

Comment: it explicitly says and emphasises the "and", so I assume you'd need to put all of uses-features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you must include them all because of the way that the permissions are stored in the API. They are stored as Strings in the [PackageManager class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html). Take for example the one you're concerned about, [android.hardware.location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_LOCATION). See how it the string is exactly the same as what you type in the Manifest. Google Play looks for these exact matches when filtering. So `android.hardware.location.gps` is not actually a child of `android.hardware.location`, it is just represented like that for the sake of organization.